# Asterisk, force timeout delay between consecutive inbound calls

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, telephony, elastix

We have one problem we've been suffering of for a long long time,It's the unknown callerID received from asterisk that happens on specific situations.

First we have a sip soft phone (sipml5)
and on server side we have

asterisk-11.25.0-0

elastix-4.0.0-1

Setup: we have any cid/did inbound route connects our calls to one ring-group(that have all the extensions)

---

The unknown caller id shows when we have:
1-Short timeout for call(which lead to make the call stick at asterisk and asterisk resent the call to extensions but with unknown caller id).. possible solution would be to make big timeout.

2-All extensions do hangup and the call stick on asterisk and asterisk resend it to extensions with unknown caller id (possible solution would be to prevent extensions doing hangup unless they answer the call first)

3-Receiving one unknown caller id lead to successive unknown caller id calls.. **no solution**

What we're trying to solve is the 3rd problem and we have an idea of forcing asterisk to wait for a specific timeout between inbound calls(we tried this manually by not allowing immediate successive calls,make 4-5 seconds delay between calls and it works fine)

---

We want to know what configuration has to be edited to force this timeout delay between inbound calls.

Answer (score -1):

You can use EPOCH function and store value somewhere(ASTDB?)

After that in dialplan compare it when dialling

No, elastic not support that and will not support it in future(weird request).